# PHP MySQL & Performance

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, iis, performance

i am setting up PHP & MySQL on my local development machine. i want to find out about things to consider for performance. some considerations i have below. i will like to hear more about optimizing my development machine for performance/best practice. i am on windows 7 x64

- IIS/Apache: i hear IIS have better performance?
- What optimizer or caching? i hear from [here](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=7114#p24683) that Optimizer+ has better performance than APC?

any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all do a profiling of your php-application to see where are the bottlenecks.
I you know the bottlenecks, you know where to cache and what to optimize.

You can profile you application with xdebug (http://www.xdebug.org/) or Zend Studio (http://www.zend.com)